# How to do I output just the formatted_address from a google api search?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying just to output the formatted-address for the input hotels in ottawa. The results give me all the data i need plus unwanted stuff. i need to truncate this. any ideas?

```
     $address = urlencode("Hotels, in Ottawa");

     $geocodeURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=hotels+in+Ottawa&sensor=false&key=mykey";
     $ch = curl_init($geocodeURL);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
     curl_close($ch);

     $geocode = json_decode($result);

     echo $result;

     //echo $formatted_address = $geocode->data[0]->formatted_address;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You think we see your code? What hotels in ottawa?

Comment: I guess it would be better to give an URL like this `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=hotels+in+Ottawa&sensor=false` and describe how exactly do you want to filter the results

Comment: that was a quick reply. was still trying to submit the code. had some issues from this end submitting it and thnx for the edit xdazz. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I've finally figured it out after all.

```
 $geocodeURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=hotels+in+Ottawa&sensor=false&key=mykey";
 $ch = curl_init($geocodeURL);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $results = curl_exec($ch);
 $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 curl_close($ch);

 $geocode = json_decode($results);

 for($i=0; $i<20; $i++){
 echo $formatted_address = $geocode->results[$i]->formatted_address;
 }
```